# How to show selected value in a DropDownList Html Helper using ViewBag in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

So I have the following scenario in which I am using two `ViewBag`(s):

1. To get the select list item
2. To get the particular item in concern

So it looks like this:

```
var currentType = "2";
List<SelectListItem> contentData = new List<SelectListItem>();
contentData.Add(new SelectListItem
{
    Text = "Show 0 only",
    Value = "0",
});

contentData.Add(new SelectListItem
{
    Text = "Show 2 Only",
    Value = "2",
});


ViewBag.currentType = currentType;
ViewBag.contentData = contentData;
```

Now in my Razor `View`, I am able to generate the `DropDownList` like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ContentTypeId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.contentData, null, new { @class = "form-control" , @style = "width: 150px;" })
```

How can I can bind my `ViewBag.currentType` on the drop down list so it shows the pre selected value by default when the component is rendered?

Is it even possible to use two `ViewBag` value in this component ?

I tried like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ContentTypeId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.contentData, null, new { @class = "form-control" , @style = "width: 150px;", @selected= (string)ViewBag.currentType})
```

But not getting the correct output.

Any tips/suggestions/solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewBag is not working in your case, you will have to select an option manually, using Selected=true. HtmlDropDown is an outdated helper too.

Using html5 select with an asp helper is the best way to select item automatically

view

```
@{

var currentType = "2";
List<SelectListItem> contentData = new List<SelectListItem>();
contentData.Add(new SelectListItem
{
    Text = "Show 0 only",
    Value = "0",
});

contentData.Add(new SelectListItem
{
    Text = "Show 2 Only",
    Value = "2",
});

//or I guess you can take the from viewbag

string currentType = ViewBag.currentType;
List<SelectListItem> contentData = ViewBag.currentData
}

.....

<select class="form-control" id="levels" asp-for="@currentType" 
asp-items="@contentData">
         <option value="0" > Select </option>
</select>
```

this is working for dropdown list

```
@{
currentType = ViewBag.currentType;
contentData = ViewBag.contentData;

var dropDownItems = new SelectList(contentData,"Value","Text", currentType);
}
.....

@Html.DropDownList("@currentType",@dropDownItems,"Select",new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I cannot place my data in a Model since it is being used for some other purpose. This is a separate module on the view and it is independent of the actual `Model`, hence I to use `ViewBag` for this only.

Comment: @RahulSharma Just try to put this model into  ViewBag and use 
@ ViewBag.ContentViewModel instead of @ Model for example.  It should be working,  i am not sure about postbak, but try to add name for control.

Comment: I tried it like this: `Html.DropDownListFor(ViewBag.currentType, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.contentData, "select type", new { @class = "form-control" })` and it is failing on the `View`.

Comment: @RahulSharma Where did you see (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) in my answer? You should try as i told Html.DropDownListFor(m=> ViewBag.currentType, ViewBag.contentData, "select type", new { @ class = "form-control" })

Comment: I am not using a strongly typed `Model` like `@Model.ContentData` so I need to cast my `ViewBag.contentData` as `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` as it is dynamic. My main problem is binding the `ViewBag.currentType` with the HTML helper.

Comment: @RahulSharma You don't need to cast a viewbag, it is a dynamic type.

Comment: I tried it and still giving me an error. Can we even use two `ViewBag` in HTML helper to bind the select list and generate the select list?

Comment: @RahulSharma I am sorry for a delay. I tested several variants and found only one that is working properly. Look at my updated answer if it fits for your  project.

Answer (score 0):

The SelectListItem Class has a Selected property.
You can just do :

```
List<SelectListItem> contentData = new List<SelectListItem>{
new SelectListItem
{
    Text = "Show 0 only",
    Value = "0",
},
new SelectListItem
{
    Text = "Show 2 Only",
    Value = "2",
    Selected = true
});
```

Comment: But how will I generate it at run-time? What will happen if my `ViewBag.currentType = currentType="0"` ? Then the above scenario will fail.

Comment: You could do Selected = currentType == "0" in the first one and Selected = currentType == 2"" in the second one

Comment: I can do that but what if my `contentData` is generated dynamically and has 50 items in it? My example is just for 2 but in real there are a lot of items in the list so I need a dynamic solution for it.

Comment: Even if you are dynamically creating SelectListItem . While you are creating it you are assigning a value to the "Value" property of the SelectListItem which means you can do Value = myDynamicItem.Value Selected = myDynamicItem.Value == currentType

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to post an answer with the attempt that I had made on this aspect and was able to achieve. I used the standard way of defining the pure `HTML` element instead of using the Razor helper tags. You can do this if you have dynamic elements which are not a part of your `Model`:

```
<select class="form-control" id="ContentDataId" name="ContentDataId">
    @foreach (SelectListItem option in ViewBag.contentData as List<SelectListItem>)
    {
        <option value="@option.Value" @(option.Value == Convert.ToString(ViewBag.currentType) ? "selected='selected'" : "")>@option.Text</option>
    }
</select>
```

The above definition will generate the same HTML if you used the helper tags. For those who have confusion using the helper tags, this is a more conventional way of generating your drop down list with dynamic `ViewBag`.